# Does the iPhone SDK really take up ~5GB every time you upgrade it?

Tags: iphone

Every time I upgrade to a new version of the SDK (beta and general releases), I noticed that installer says it's going to take up around 5-6 GB of space. After several upgrades you would expect your hard drive to be full.

Doesn't it just update the files that were changed? Or does it uninstall the old version (thus freeing around 5-6 GB of space) and then install the new version? Or does it really take up an additional 5-6 GB of space?

**Update:** I'm installing to the same location it was installed before.

**Update:** Will it automatically delete the old files which are no longer necessary in this new SDK and are simply taking up room?

Comment: If you install the new SDK to the same location as the old one, most files will be overwritten in place as they are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it overwrites your existing install unless you specify a custom install location.